# Image.GetThumbnailImage throws OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, winforms

The following C# 3.5 code throws an exception in GetThumbnailImage:

```
Image img = null;
Image scaledImg = null;

byte[] imageData = File.ReadAllBytes("11001.jpg");
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageData);
img = Image.FromStream(stream);
stream.Close();
stream.Dispose();

scaledImg = img.GetThumbnailImage(64, 64, null, IntPtr.Zero);
```

The problem is the disposing of the stream. If I remove the Close() and Dispose() statement, everything works fine. Does anyone know why this exception is thrown? Using a callback instead of null as parameter does not change the behavior.

I don't need a solution, I can use new Bitmap(img, new Size(width, height) for scaling. This is probably better and shoud have been used from the beginning.

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the exception only occurs in WindowsXP. Win7 and Win8 seem to handle the above code just fine.

Comment: only call one => Dispose auto Closes and releases the handle.

Comment: Or just use `using`.

Comment: I assume you're not using `Image.FromFile` because the real code is a bit more complicated, right?

Comment: The real code uses resources, not files. And the loading of the image and the resizing are in different parts, so delaying the dispose after the resize is not really possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetThumbnailImage` is a native method, using the same stream you passed while creating the `Image`. Only the .NET methods are using the actual data from the stream (it's loaded as the last thing while creating the image from a stream).

It's a pretty typical leaky abstraction. You thought you have an `Image` object that already has its data loaded, but the data is only loaded in the .NET part. Any method that works directly with the GDI+ image handle will still need the stream to be live.

Another example of the same problem is while trying to save the image in a different format. When you try to save with the same format, .NET just saves the byte data it has in memory, simple. If it's *not* the same, it will use the GDI+ method `SaveImageToFile`, which again requires the original stream to be preserved.

If you don't mind having the stream alive, you can just move the `Dispose` after everything you do with the images produced from that stream:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(imageData))
{
  var img = Image.FromStream(stream);
  var scaledImg = img.GetThumbnailImage(64, 64, null, IntPtr.Zero);

  scaledImg.Save(...);
}
```

If you do mind, the easiest thing you can do is this:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(stream));
```

The `Bitmap` constructor will copy the image data, and you no longer need to keep the stream.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `GetThumbnailImage` uses the stream to do its job so it needs it to be open.You can do it like this :

```
Image img = null;
Image scaledImg = null;

byte[] imageData = File.ReadAllBytes("11001.jpg");
using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageData))
{
img = Image.FromStream(stream);
scaledImg = img.GetThumbnailImage(64, 64, null, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

([using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) closes and disposes the MemoryStream but it also handles exceptional situations to avoid memory leaks)

Answer (score 0):

The Image object uses lazy evaluation. As you have already closed the stream, when it actually tries to read the image in order to get the thumbnail, it's not there anymore. Hence the error.